# SLF4J fails on war deployment with Weblogic

Tags: java, logging, weblogic-10.x, slf4j

I deploy a war file on weblogic 10.3.3 but encounter this error.

```
    <May 7, 2012 2:40:10 PM ICT> <Error> <Deployer> <VIEAE747399> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1336376410618> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1336376405480' for task '2'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "quotation-service" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "service-quotation.war".
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in URL [zip:C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/a2_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/service-quotation/aio4oc/war/WEB-INF/lib/quotation-storage-2_0_0.jar!/config/quotation-storage-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [zip:C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/a2_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/service-quotation/aio4oc/war/WEB-INF/lib/quotation-storage-2_0_0.jar!/config/quotation-storage-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
...

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:130)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory could not be successfully initialized. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#unsuccessfulInit
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:282)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:248)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:261)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:197)
... 76 more
```

In WEB-INF/lib of service-quotation.war, below files are included

```
log4j-1.2.16.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
```

I appreciate any suggestion, hints.

Notes: I deployed this war with success on Tomcat 6.

Comment: Is there any error message being logged before that exception or any info after it? `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory could not be successfully initialized` doesn't happen without a reason and you are normally told about that reason.

Comment: @Thomas, that's all error messages I have. I suspect that I need to add those jar files to weblogic but I'm not sure where to put them in.

Comment: Did you read the webpage mentioned in the exception?  If so, what happened when you tried what it suggests?

Comment: I've read but didn't find the solution there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,

Finally I find the solution to fix log4j error. I add below weblogic.xml file to WEB-INF folder to instruct weblogic to use slf4j jars inside the war file. I even needn't to add
those jar files into weblogic installation folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE weblogic-web-app PUBLIC "-//BEA
Systems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 7.0//EN"
"http://www.bea.com/servers/wls700/dtd/weblogic700-web-jar.dtd">
<weblogic-web-app>
<container-descriptor>
<prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Then, in order to overcome hibernate problem I add below line to the first code line in file setDomainEnv.cmd to enable hiberante shared library in weblogic

```
 set PRE_CLASSPATH=%PRE_CLASSPATH%;C:\Oracle\Middleware\modules\javax.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-0.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\modules\com.oracle.jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-1.jar
```

(pls first check above filepaths are existed)

Hope this helpful for those who need.